# \fontsize command not working as expected

Tags: tables, fonts, fontsize

I have some tables in the middle of a document which is in written in `12pt` and I'm trying to make them in `10pt`. Only the tables. If I write

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\fontsize{10}{12}
\begin{tabular}{clcc}\hline
Variable & flag & flag & Height \\\hline
$q$ & Specific & a & 46.46\\
$c$ & \CO2 & b & 46.46
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

then only the first column gets passed into `10pt`. I have tried everything and the only thing that made it work is

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{clcc}\hline
Variable & flag & flag & Height \\\hline
$q$ & Specific & a & 46.46\\
$c$ & \CO2 & b & 46.46
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This doesn't look like the correct way to do it for me. What the proper way to achieve what I want and why doesn't a simple `\fontsize` work?

Comment: The `\selectfont` is indeed required to "activate" the `\fontsize` macro.

Comment: For example, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document

Comment: @egreg: Really? I would have staked my life on it.  I'll remove it  and post another comment. Thanks!

Comment: But you might as well write `\footnotesize`. It is equivalent, if the document size is 12pt.

Comment: @Bernard In `size12.clo` you find `\newcommand\footnotesize{\@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xpt\@xiipt...}`

Comment: I see. I confess I don't look into the files in ltxbase every day ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts in LaTeX are characterized by several attributes:

- encoding
- family
- series
- shape
- size
- baseline skip

For each of the attributes there is a low level command

- `\fontencoding`
- `\fontfamily`
- `\fontseries`
- `\fontshape`
- `\fontsize`

The last command has two arguments, because it sets both the size and the baseline skip.

It would be quite inefficient if each of those command immediately did a font selection, so the system works by first setting the attributes and then applying a `\selectfont` command.

Higher level commands such as `\itshape` already do the `\selectfont` by themselves as well as `\small` or similar commands.

So your `\fontsize{10}{12}` declaration is incomplete: some internal parameters are set, but no particular font is chosen. You have to add `\selectfont` either explicitly or implicitly by means of a higher level command.

In your case, just using `\footnotesize` would do: when the main body font is 12pt, `\footnotesize` chooses a 10pt font.

It's always better using a higher level command.

Comment: I preferred using the low-level command because in case the document goes back to being `10pt` (as it will someday) then the font in the table will still be the same size. Great answer, though, although I still fail to see what the `\fontsize` command does if you still have to use a `\selectfont` command.